# I, and I/me alone, did it all

Tags: personal-pronouns, parentheticals, objective-case

> *I, and **I/me** alone, did it all*.

Which option, *I* or *me*, and why, should be used in a parenthetical like this one?

Secondly, is it the same situation as in ***Me/I** alone, I did it* ?

Answer (score 1):

You use "I" because it's part of the subject; putting it in a parenthetical with a qualifier doesn't change the pronoun that's used.

"Me" is used in an object, so you could say

> He gave it to me, and me alone.

Comment: _**Me/I** alone, I did it all_ ? which one here?

Comment: It's the subject, so it's **I**.